# Converting data points over time into total count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time

I am trying to do some time trend analysis of cyclone data but am having difficulties getting the pd dataframe into a format where I can do that...

Right now the dataframe looks like this:

|  | date | season | stormid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1970-01-04 12:00:00 | 1970 | SH071970 |
| 1 | 1970-01-04 18:00:00 | 1970 | SH071970 |
| 2 | 1970-01-05 00:00:00 | 1970 | SH071970 |
| 3 | 1970-01-05 06:00:00 | 1970 | SH071970 |
| 4 | 1970-01-05 12:00:00 | 1970 | SH071970 |
| 5 | 1970-01-05 18:00:00 | 1970 | SH071970 |
| 6 | 1970-01-06 00:00:00 | 1970 | SH071970 |
| 7 | 1970-01-06 06:00:00 | 1970 | SH071970 |
| 8 | 1970-01-06 12:00:00 | 1970 | SH071970 |
| 9 | 1970-01-06 18:00:00 | 1970 | SH071970 |
| 10 | 1970-01-07 00:00:00 | 1970 | SH071970 |

And I would like to have all the entries across days somehow combined into a total day count, for example like this:

|  | start date | end date | days | season | stormid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1970-01-04 | 1970-01-11 | 15 | 1970 | SH071870 |

So on and so forth for all the different stormids.

Comment: can you explain the `15`? Is this a dummy number? It should rather be `2` if you count the number of days elapsed, or `11` if you count the number of rows in the group

Comment: Yes @mozway this was a dummy number just to show the visuals. Thanks for pointing it out and my next post I will write which are and aren’t dummy.

Comment: So have you checked my answer below? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the number of days between the min and max per group, use [`numpy.ptp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ptp.html) and [`Timedelta.days`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.days.html):

```
import numpy as np

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

out = (df.groupby(['season', 'stormid'], as_index=False)
         .agg(days=('date', lambda s: np.ptp(s).days),
              start_date=('date', lambda s: s.min().normalize()),
              end_date=('date', lambda s: s.max().normalize())
             )
       )
```

*NB. `lambda s: np.ptp(s).days` is equivalent to `lambda s: (s.max()-s.min()).days`?  If you want to **round up** use `lambda s: (s.max()-s.min()).ceil('D').days` (getting 3 days here).*

Output:

```
   season   stormid  days start_date   end_date
0    1970  SH071970     2 1970-01-04 1970-01-07
```

##### alternative

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

out = (df.groupby(['season', 'stormid'], as_index=False)
         .agg(start_date=('date', lambda s: s.min().normalize()),
              end_date=('date', lambda s: s.max().normalize())
             )
         .assign(days=lambda d: d['end_date'].sub(d['start_date']).dt.days)
       )
```

Output:

```
   season   stormid start_date   end_date  days
0    1970  SH071970 1970-01-04 1970-01-07     3
```

##### counts

If you simply want the number of rows per group (which is not really "days"):

```
out = (df.groupby(['season', 'stormid'], as_index=False)
         .agg(days=('date', 'size'))
       )
```

Output:

```
   season   stormid  days
0    1970  SH071970    11
```

Comment: Thanks! The 'alternative' solution worked great for me! @mozway